# Styling @Html.CheckBoxFor as a slider

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, slider, html-helper

I'm having trouble styling a checkbox generated by `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` as a slider.

I've identified the "culprit" to be the hidden input field. I've made a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t2ojpY) to illustrate the problem. It contains 3 checkboxes - one generated by `@Html.CheckBoxFor()`, the second one using the code generated by `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` with the hidden input commented out and the third classic checkbox.

You will see the slider is not working for the first one. I do need to use `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` because I want the checkbox to be bound to a property on my model, but can't figure out how to make the slider styling work...

In my view I have:

```
<div class="slider">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked, new { @class = "toggle-pill" })
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsChecked, new { @class = "toggle-label" })
</div>
```

The .css for styling it:

```
.slider [type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.slider .toggle-label {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ed495c;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: background 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider .toggle-label::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #d1d1d1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.slider [type="checkbox"]:checked + .toggle-label {
    background: #93ed49;
}

.slider [type="checkbox"]:checked + .toggle-label::before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

The model property, `IsChecked`, is typeof `bool`.

Comment: You need to put a bit more detail of the code in your question in order for an answer to be added. But I have [forked the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GRCvNQ) to show that using `@CheckBoxFor()` can work - just requires minor modification of the css

Comment: your fiddle fixed it.. submit the answer, so I can accept it. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your css for `.slider [type="checkbox"]:checked + .toggle-label {` and `.slider [type="checkbox"]:checked + .toggle-label::before {` use the [adjacent sibling combinator (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) which selects the next sibling.

Because `CheckboxFor()` generates a `<input type="hidden" .. />` immediately after the `<input type="checkbox" .. />`, the selector is choosing the wrong element (the hidden input, not the label).

You need to modify the css to use the [general sibling combinator (~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors),  so that your css becomes

```
.slider [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .toggle-label {
    background: #93ed49;
}

.slider [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .toggle-label::before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

I assume your using a plugin for this, so you can either modify the original file, or add an additional css file containing the above.

Refer [this forked fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GRCvNQ) to see how it works.