# How to configure Checkboxes Materialize Css in Web application Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, materialize, html-helper

How do I configure Checkboxes in Asp.Net MVC Razor.

Since in the documentation we have the following configuration Materialize for checkboxes :

```
<p>
   <label>
     <input type = "checkbox" />
     <span> Network </span>
   </label>
</p>
```

**And in Razor I could not perform this configuration.**

```
<div class = "input-field col s12">
        @Html.EditorFor (model => model.AnnualDestaque)
        @Html.LabelFor (model => model.AnnualDestaque)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor (model => model.AnnualDestaque, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
</div>
```

Comment: You need to modify the css to use a general sibling combinator (~) - refer [Styling @Html.CheckBoxFor as a slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217712/styling-html-checkboxfor-as-a-slider/46218643#46218643) for a similar issue (materialize.css uses an adjacent sibling combinator but that will not work because your `EditorFor()` is generating hidden input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include model Name in your cshtml page

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.Test
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
 {
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeName)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.IsSelected)

  </div>

   <input type="submit" value="Save" />

  </div>
}
```

Model

```
public class Test
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Even though this way not described above, the checkbox does not appear on the screen, noting that I'm using MaterializeCss, the checkbox does not appear on the screen

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a checkbox binded with your model like that :

```
public class Network
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Just use :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Selected)
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name)
```

Comment: Even though this way not described above, the checkbox does not appear on the screen, noting that I'm using MaterializeCss, the checkbox does not appear on the screen

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't mentioned the fact that you are using a custom plugin for checkboxes. In this cases the proper way is to implement a custom helper.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it, and I am passing the answer.

**I used Html Helper** [Documentation Html Helper MVC](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-checkbox-checkboxfor)

**It worked perfectly without mistakes the way it's meant to be.**

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <label>
        <input data-val="true"
                data-val-required="The Advertisement field is required."
                id="Advertisement"/**** m => m.Advertisement ****/
                name="Advertisement"/**** m => m.Advertisement ****/
                type="checkbox"
                value="true" />

        <span>Anuncio Destaque</span>

        <input name="Advertisement" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work doing this:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="FIELDNAME" id="FIELDNAME" value="true" class="filled-in" @(Model.FIELDNAME? "checked" : "") />
<span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FIELDNAME)</span>
</label>
<input name="FIELDNAME" type="hidden" value="false" />
```